# Represent postfix and prefix increment and decrement in AST and grammar

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, lexer, post-increment

I have those rules to build a simple calculator :

```
statement -> assignment | calculation
assignment -> variable '=' sum end
calculation -> sum end
sum -> product (('+' product)|('-' product))*
product -> factor (('*' factor)|('/' factor))*
factor -> term
term ->  variable | number
```

My problem is how to model the rules for postfix and prefix increment and decrement. How can represent it in this grammar above so that, for example, if I have the assignment :

```
x=1
j=x++ +2
```

the result will be `j=3` and `x=2`. How do I do post-increment after assignment?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest grammar change would be to add the new operators to `term`:

```
term ->  variable
      | '++' variable | '--' variable
      | variable '++' | variable '--'
      | number
```

The new rules could have been added to `factor` instead, particularly since `factor` currently has no point at all and could be removed. However, if you ever add more complicated lvalues than a single variable (array subscripts for example) then that will have to be adjusted. Also, adding the operators to `factor` would make nonsense like `++2` syntactically possible, or `(a+b)++` once you implement parentheses. So, although putting them in some non-terminal other than `term` is more common and probably more appropriate, it's not necessarily the best solution in this particular case.

The questions about the AST and the evaluation of the AST can't be answered without knowing a lot more about how you structure your ASTs. You're free to build ASTs in any way you feel appropriate, but it's probably worth noting that the AST must be able to distinguish between post- and pre-increment. Either you need to use a different operator symbol for the two cases, or you need some hack (such as the C++ hack of adding a fake operand to one of the two cases).

Comment: Thanks, now i have a problem to evaluate the post inc/dec as updating the variable which 
get inc after the term is finished

Comment: @user63898: Why do you find that complicated? There are two completely independent things: the value you store for the variable, and the value you return as the value of the operator. As long as you keep these two ideas separate in your head, you will find no problem at all in implementing pre- and post-increment. If you really can't figure it out, ask a new question but including the details of how you build and evaluate your AST, and why it doesn't work in the way you want it to.